# Android. Switch between 2 activities without re-creating and finishing

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activities "A" and "B". 
I need to switch between them without finishing and recreating.

*Run app -> create and show A -> press button -> create and show B -> press button -> show already exist A -> press button -> show already exist B -> and so on.*

**Current solution:**

```
private void toA() {
    Intent intentToA = new Intent(this, A.class);
    intentToA.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intentToA);
}

private void toB() {
    Intent intentToB = new Intent(this, B.class);
    intentToB.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intentToB);
}
```

It works on VM (native, Genymotion - android 4.1). Activities will created only once. And when I switch between them, everyting is okay - no calls of the onCreate or onDestroy. It is exactly what I want.

But when I run same app on real device (Nexus 4 - android 4.3) activities are destroyed and recreated while switching.

**on VM:**

```
Run app -> 
A: onCreate, onResume -> 
press button -> 
B: onCreate, onResume -> 
press button -> 
A: onResume - > 
press button -> 
B: onResume -> 
...
```

**on Real Device:**

```
Run app -> 
A: onCreate, onResume -> 
press button -> 
B: onCreate, onResume & A: onDestroy ->
press buttom ->
A: onCreate, onResume & B: onDestory ->
...
```

**Note:** Intent flag has no effect on the switch behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `launchMode` of Activities to `singleInstance` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay. I got it. I set launchMode to singleInstance in my 2 activities. But I did one more thing: on my device in dev settings was checked "Dont save the actions. Remove a summary of actions after their completion." Thanks.